# Unfamiliar trac warning message

Tags: linux, svn, apache, trac

I'm currently trying to configure Subversion/Apache/Trac and I've run into an error that I have never seen before and that google has not yet indexed:

**2010-11-03 11:49:50,335 Trac[api] WARNING: Found no repositories matching '/path/to/repos/tests/' base.**

Does anyone know what this could be about?

Thank you very much for your time and attention.

Comment: Might be better on [Serverfault](http://serverfault.com)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hate when I end up asking questions before I completely understands the problem. The issue was that I still hadn't finished configuring Trac. The file "trac.ini" should contain something like this:

```
[repositories]
tests.dir = /var/svn/tests
tests.description = Test repository.
tests.type = svn
tests.url = http://reposurl/tests
```

Sorry.